# Laravel & vuejs cpanel share hosting app migration problem

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cpanel

I'm sorry for my English.

Good day, developers,

I need your help, I have an app that I must migrate https://creamedicinaprepagada.com/ It is developed in Laravel + VueJS, at the moment it is hosted in AWS CPANEL, but I must migrate to CPANEL HOSTINGER. I am passing all the files and databases from the AWS CPANEL to CPANEL HOSTINGER, the app i did not develop it and those are the only files I have.

In the first image you can see the public html and in the second what the AppGestorContenido folder contains.

[image: Valid XHTML]

[image: Valid XHTML]

It gives me error 500.

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(785): Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider->Illuminate\Events\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#2 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('events', Array)
#3 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(767): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('events', Array)
#4 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1227): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('events')
#5 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php(40): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('events')
#6 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(785): Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#7 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#8 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('router', Array)
#9 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(767): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('router', Array)
#10 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(927): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('router')
#11 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(855): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#12 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(816): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#13 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Kernel')
#14 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(265): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Http\\Kernel', Array, false)
#15 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(785): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#16 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#17 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#18 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(767): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...', Array)
#19 /home/tucachivache/public_html/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#20 {main}
  thrown in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/EventServiceProvider.php on line 18
[17-Feb-2021 21:54:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[17-Feb-2021 21:54:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[17-Feb-2021 21:54:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher' not found in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/EventServiceProvider.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(785): Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider->Illuminate\Events\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#1 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#2 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('events', Array)
#3 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(767): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('events', Array)
#4 /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGest in /home/tucachivache/public_html/AppGestorContenido/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/EventServiceProvider.php on line 18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you are missing the vendor folder from laravel

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf ./vendor

composer install

php artisan migrate
my bee this worked